# Serpy .to_represenatiaon

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Does [serpy](https://github.com/clarkduvall/serpy) have an equivalent `.to_representation` like in [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#advanced-serializer-usage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serpy has the `.to_value` method that can be overridden to perform custom serialization akin to DRFs `.to_representation`.

You'll likely want to call the base class first within your `.to_value` method.

```
def to_value(self, instance):
    data = super(BaseClass, self).to_value()
    # do some custom manipulation
    return data
```